# Handling expection catch block - xdebug

Tags: php, exception, xdebug

I am new to exceptions, so I am trying to learn it.

The first thing what I've tired now is to copy paste the code from the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) doc:

```
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    return 1 / $x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo "Hello World\n";
```

Document says, output will be:

```
0.2
Caught exception: Division by zero.
Hello World
```

I expected this output, because as I know this is the point of the exception handling that not show that ugly big error code with trace.

Instead of this output I've get:

```
0.2
( ! ) Exception: Division by zero. in D:\Apache\htdocs\SO\index.php on line 10
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  363040  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0009  363584  inverse( )  ...\index.php:17
Caught exception: Division by zero. Hello World
```

Why do am I getting this error? I am using xDebug, could that be the reason of this? If yes, what should I do programmaticaly to not get this error but what php document wrote.

**UPDATE:**

If I am adding the `xdebug_disable();` before the `try` it works normal, and get the expected output.

My original question turns to: how to handle exception and not show this ugly error when xdebug enabled?

Comment: I just checked your code here : https://eval.in/746991

Comment: @Niklesh Yes, I see. I've updated my question.

Comment: I don't think its ugly, Its more detailed view of error for which you installed `xdebug`

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want permanently you can uninstall that extension.
To disable specific areas, check the extenstion `extension_loaded`, and disable like this.

```
if (extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
  xdebug_disable();
}
```

Comment: It wont uninstall the extension, just do not show the errors. I've read the doc: "Disable showing stack traces on error conditions" https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions That should be the first thing what I check, the doc. Sorry, deadline was today.

Comment: Yes `extension_loaded` only checks whether it is installed or not.

Comment: Yes, but extension_load is not relevant to what I sad. I talked about the behaviour of `xdebug_disable;` That just turn off errors, nothing else.

Comment: @vaso123 : I think you are right, I just updated my answer with blank space. Now you can uncheck accepted mark. so that people will know, this question is not answered yet.